What is the proper way to say "voice direction" in German?
I am working on the credits of a video game and at one point there is a woman credited with "voice direction," i.e. she directed the voice actors. What is the best concise way to say this in German? I cannot find this phrase in any dictionary.
Google Translate gives me "Sprachregie" but I am not sure that is right. Not only is it not in the dictionary, but looking it up on linguee.de or context.reverso.net I see it also means "control room." If I search for "voice direction" there, I do not get "Sprachregie."
I assume I need a compound word but I am not sure what elements to construct it from. "Synchronsprechen" is voice acting, "Synchronsprecher" are voice actors but these are quite long words; could I use "Sprecher" (speakers) or "Stimmen" (voices) instead? As for "direction" I am not sure if it would be Leitung, Regie or Direktion. Alternatively I could use a word like "Leiterin" for "director."
Please advise. What would sound most natural with the fewest number of letters? Sprecherregie?

I am not 100% if there is a 1-1 correspondence with voice direction, as a title but usually directing voice actors is called Dialogregie in German. Someone doing that job would then be a Dialogregisseur/Dialogregisseurin (m/f).

The "Regie" (from French, hence spoken "re-zhe", IPA: [ʁeˈʒiː] or [ʁɛˈʒiː], but ultimately from latin "regere", to direct) is the position to direct. I.e. in Latin the "rex" (king) is the one doing it. The person doing the "Regie" would be the "Regisseur" (director).
"Sprache" (from "sprechen", to speak) here doesn't mean "language" but "(things dealing with) the spoken" - the speakers.
Therefore: "Sprachregie" - the position to direct the speakers. It is exactly the correct word and absolutely idiomatic. Even Google gets something right sometimes.
PS: yes, "Sprachregie" could also mean the room where all this happens and the "Sprachregie" (the position) is doing its work. This is similar to saying "the parliament has decided ..." - of course not the building, but the people holding office there.

"re-she" is pretty close, but the sh is voiced.

@RHa: unfortunately IPA is not my forte. If you know it you are welcome to edit it in.

@RHa: thank you!

Though in "Regierung" (government) the "g" is hard.
